# Graham-Cassidy: Where does this name come from?

Tags: united-states, healthcare

I'm puzzled, something which sounds remarkably like the recent US proposals to reform (or at least, significantly change) the health care system has emerged as a proposal named Graham-Cassidy.

There's quite a lot of material online about the contents of the proposal, and about strong objections to it. I'm trying to find out why it's called Graham-Cassidy, is it named after someone? Someones?

Comment: It's named after Lindsey Graham and Bill Cassidy. The better question is probably why it's named after them (why are they especially relevant, is it a marketing term, who came up with the name, why not someone elses name,...), but even that doesn't seem that interesting (they are the bills sponsors, so it's their name on it).

Comment: I looked at the first five Google results for "Graham-Cassidy", and four of them mention Sens. Graham and Cassidy, and three of them explicitly say it was named after them. I don't see how this is such a puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [many bills](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jun/19/nation/la-na-0620-titles-20110620), Graham-Cassidy is named after its two lead sponsors:  Lindsey Graham, Senator of South Carolina; Bill Cassidy, Senator of Louisiana.

Some other examples:

- [Sarbanes-Oxley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarbanes%E2%80%93Oxley_Act)
- [Gramm-Rudman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramm%E2%80%93Rudman%E2%80%93Hollings_Balanced_Budget_Act)
- [Kemp-Roth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_Recovery_Tax_Act_of_1981)

These bills also have other, official names, but people often find it more convenient to name bills after the sponsors to differentiate them from similar bills.